# apache james, jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, james

I am trying to make a mail application through apache james, but I could not really get all the 
things, please give suggestions how to use it. MOreover, I could not figure it how to use jsp and servlet for james. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to send e-mails or receive and process them?

Comment: yes sir, but I could not even figure out how to install it. please help

Comment: What is your environment? Tomcat, JBoss (or other), standalone? Also, do you want to send e-mails, receive them or both?

Comment: Tomcat actually, yes both, send e-mails and receive emails as well. please tell me what to do and how to do?

Comment: Any reason to use specifically james? Just by looking at the documentation it is very confusing and lacking a lot of stuff. Why not go with another mail server?

Comment: no actually, I have waisted a lot of time on it, now i able to configure it and send and retrieve message as well. but again I got problems.. if u suggest any other java server please name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments there are two actions you want to do:

- Send emails - quite easy with the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)
- Retrieve emails - You can do it with the JavaMail API using either IMAP or POP3. Set A scheduler to trigger the retrieval. (either [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). cron job + servlet, or perhaps even the [Java timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) will do)